# How do I manually Dispose RSACryptoServiceProvider?

Tags: c#, dispose, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I have read on MSDN([see Important note](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.aspx)) that RSACryptoServiceProvider must be disposed. They give the example:

```
using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
```

Now I'm trying to include RSACryptoServiceProvider into MyClass making use of it in several Methods. With this setup I cannot use the using statement.

Instead I try to call the .Dispose() Method of the RSACryptoServiceProvider object at a suitable time but then I get the compile error message:

> `System.Security.Cryptography.AsymmetricAlgorithm.Dispose(bool)' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Is RSACryptoServiceProvider not supposed to be used longer than one function call(using the using statement)?

How can I fix this, is not making the Dispose call an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Clear](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.asymmetricalgorithm.clear.aspx) method looks like it will call the dispose method:

> This method is a simple call to the IDisposable.Dispose method.
>   Calling Dispose allows the resources used by the AsymmetricAlgorithm class to be reallocated for other purposes. For more information about Dispose, see Cleaning Up Unmanaged Resources.

Comment: @phq: Alternatively, if for some reason you *insist* upon calling Dispose, then cast the value to IDisposable, and then call Dispose on the result of the cast.  But better to do what the documentation says and call Clear.